# Mac OS Cocoa Showing and Hiding Views

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to create a Mac OS app that is similar to iTunes. That is, I have a controller on the left hand side of my app that is a source list. When the user clicks on one of the entries in the list, I want to show the associated view on the right side. I've found several answered questions and even a tutorial on the subject, but they very old in Mac OS years. They use Objective C and nibs while I use Swift 3 and the Storyboard.

So far I've coded a Source View. When I click on the entries in the list, this function is called in ViewController.swift:

```
func outlineViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
  guard let outlineView = notification.object as? NSOutlineView else {
    return
  }
  let selectedIndex = outlineView.selectedRow
}
```

I'll use the index to determine which view to display. If I set up additional views and controllers, how do I get handles to them? You would think this would be pretty common. I don't need code, just a general idea on how to proceed or a tutorial I've missed in my search.

Has there been any major changes in the area of switching views? I have a Container View on the right to hold the views that the app will switch between. Is that necessary?

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682179/loading-views-into-nscontainerview-with-swift)

Comment: Your questions are confusing. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I don't know what your questions are about.  Are you just talking about outlineView?  Changes between what - Objective-C and Swift or Swift 2.3 and Swift 3?

Comment: how about using a tabview without tabs and switching based on the side bar selection... yet you could use view controller for each of the possible views of the right side and just load them as needed and have an empty view or a splitview or a stackview as container...

Comment: The linked question didn't solve my problem, but it seems to be a good solution in general. I'm just accepting to close this one.